# Site.com Discontinued?

Tags: site.com

Today I found out that Salesforce discontinues the Site.com Workbook.

> **Site.com Workbook Discontinued**
>
> We’re discontinuing the Site.com Workbook in Winter ’15.
>   Other than the workbook, however, all other Salesforce Help and user assistance remains in place to support Site.com customers fully.
>
> [- W15 Release Notes: Site.com Workbook Discontinued](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_sitecom_workbook.htm)

Therefore my question is: **Is Salesforce discontinuing site.com?**

In the spring release notes salesforce mentions that you can use "the newly expanded Community Builder to [do X] - **with no need to go back to Site.com Studio.**" - (RN Spring15 p53)

Or there is another quote:

> You **still** use Site.com Studio to drag and drop or delete page elements.
>
> (RN Spring15 p57)

From my point of view it looks like salesforce wants to replace site.com Studio with Salesforce Community Designer.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is what has changed is that Site.com cannot be purchased on its own and is only available to be purchased with Communities at this point. The Site.com Studio is still available to be used and is still being actively added to with new features and functionality.

Comment: Hey Peter that for your answer. I found some lines about site.com in the release notes of string '15 (added it to the question). I think it looks like they want to replace site.com...